# How to make a cluster of GitLab instances

Tags: gitlab, cluster-computing, scalability, multiple-instances

Is it possible to create a cluster of multiple GitLab instances (multiple machines)? My instance is over utilized and I would like to add other machines, but at the same for the user should be transparent to access his project, he doesn't care which instance it will be hosted on.

What could be the best solution to help the users?

I'm on GitLab Community Edition 10.6.4

Thanks for your help,

Leonardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you are talking about scaling GitLab server, not GitLab runners.

GitLab Omnibus is a fairly complex system with multiple components, some are stateless and some are stateful.

If you currently have everything on the same server, the easiest option is to scale up (move to bigger machine).

If you can't, you can extract stateful components to host them separately: PostgreSQL, Redis, files to NFS.
Funnily you can make performance worse here.
Next step you can scale out the stateless side.

But it is in no way an easy task.
I'd suggest to start with setting up proper monitoring to see where are your limitations (CPU, RAM, IO) and bottle-necks (in which components).

[image: architecture]

See docs, including some examples of scaling:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/high_availability/
  https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/high-availability/
- https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/architecture.html
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/high_availability/gitlab.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I'm talking about GitLab Servers. I'll evaluate your interesting proposal. On the other hand, suppose I setup two full servers instances. Is it possible/simple to move repositories and related data (pipeline history, etc) from one to the other? I know about export/import functionalities for each project, but is there also a built-in feature to do the move between two instances without using the import/export?

Comment: Apart from export/import, I'm not aware of any official ways to move projects